# Why does requesting this URL with my code give a 405 response?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to login with python in the following url: https://micuenta.consultatioplus.com/#!/login

Can someone help me?

I tried this but it gave me: Response 405

```
import requests

url = 'https://micuenta.consultatioplus.com/#!/login'

login =  {'formPosted':'1', 'login_email':'me@example.com', 'password':'pw'}

requests.post('https://micuenta.consultatioplus.com/#!/login', login)
```

Edit:

I tried the following code:

```
import requests

url = 'https://micuenta.consultatioplus.com'
login =  { 'username':'ex', 'password':'pw'}
endpoint = '#!/login'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'}

s= requests.Session()



r=requests.Session().get(url+endpoint,headers=headers, auth=('ex', 'pw'))
```

But i got a message when i try to run r.text and I cant scrap the web. The menssage is:

'\n\n\n\n    \n    \n    \n    \n    \n    \n    \n\n\n\n\n    \n    You are using an outdated</strong> browser. Please 

upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>\n    \n\n    \n    \n

\n    \n\n    \n\n    \n\n    \n    \n    \n\n    \n        \n            \n                \n                    Volver arriba

\n                \n                \n                    \n                        \n                            \n                                \n                                    \n                                        LinkedIN\n                                    \n                                \n                                \n                                    \n                                        Twitter\n                                    \n                                \n                                \n                                    \n                                        Facebook\n                                    \n                                \n                                \n                                    \n                                        YouTube\n                                    \n                                \n                                \n                                    \n                                        WhatsApp\n                                    \n                                \n                            \n                            \n                                \n                                    \n                                \n                                \n                                    \n                                \n                            \n                        \n                    \n                \n                \n                    Volver arriba \n                \n            \n        \n

---

\n        \n            \n                \n                    \n                    â\x92¸ 2011-2018

\n                \n                \n

Se hace saber al pÃºblico inversor, que ciertas compaÃ±Ã\xadas locales y extranjeras ofrecen servicios en\n                        diversos medios de comunicaciÃ³n, sobre productos como bonos, acciones, contratos de futuros y opciones,\n                        fideicomisos, fondos de inversiÃ³n, sin contar con la autorizaciÃ³n correspondiente del Organismo.\n                        Los ofrecimientos realizados a inversores locales desde el extranjero que permitan operar a travÃ©s\n                        de plataformas informÃ¡ticas o pÃ¡ginas de Internet, representan un alto riesgo para el pÃºblico inversor.\n                        Por ello, se advierte sobre los elevados riesgos de pÃ©rdida de capital que potencialmente podrÃ\xada acarrear\n                        efectuar inversiones a travÃ©s de entidades no autorizadas, y las consecuencias que puede traer aparejada\n                        la infracciÃ³n a la Ley NÂ° 26.831 de Oferta PÃºblica. Si desea conocer la lista de Agentes registrados en\n                        la ComisiÃ³n Nacional de Valores,\n                        cliquee aquÃ\xad.\n

\n

Los rendimientos pasados no son indicativos de rendimientos futuros. Las inversiones en Fondos Comunes\n                        de InversiÃ³n pueden importar riesgos, incluyendo la posible pÃ©rdida de la inversiÃ³n. Las inversiones en\n                        cuotapartes de fondos no constituyen depÃ³sitos en Banco de Valores S.A a los fines de la ley de entidades\n                        financieras ni cuentan con ninguna de las garantÃ\xadas que tales depÃ³sitos a la vista o a plazo puedan gozar\n                        de acuerdo a la legislaciÃ³n y reglamentaciÃ³n aplicables en materia de depÃ³sitos en entidades financieras.\n

\n                \n                \n                    \n                        \n                    \n                    \n                        \n                    \n                    \n                        FATCA\n                        PEP\n                        Sujeto Obligado\n                        Honorarios\n                        CÃ³digo de conducta\n                        TÃ©rminos y condiciones\n                    \n                \n            \n        \n

---

\n    \n\n\n    \n    \n    window.$zopim||(function(d,s){var z=$zopim=function(c){z.*.push(c)},$=z.s=d.createElement(s),e=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];z.set=function(o){z.set.*.push(o)};z.*=[];z.set.*=[];$.async=!0;$.setAttribute("charset","utf-8");$.src="https://v2.zopim.com/?3OTfL1bHShoSWH5u6KokZWmTcz52y7Mk";z.t=+new Date;$.type="text/javascript";e.parentNode.insertBefore($,e)})(document,"script");\n    \n    \n\n\n    \n\n    \n\n\n\n'

The status code is 200, but this is not the text that the page shows its only the bottom of the page. Can someone help me?

Comment: lower case import for one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd encourage you to check out the `Session` object described in the `requests` documentation here: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/

But `requests` is so mature and well written that you can often just try basic auth as described here: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/#basic-authentication

In short, you could try:

```
import requests

url = 'https://micuenta.consultatioplus.com'
endpoint = '/endpoint-you-ultimately-want'

requests.get(url+endpoint, auth=('me@example.com', 'pw'))
```

Comment: Hi, this worked but now I have another problem. I cant get the text of the web Im searching, it appears a message that says "You are using an <strong>outdated</strong>" Do you know how to solve it?

Sorry im very new at this. Thanks

Comment: @SantiagoNunez is it a message or an error? If it's an error please post the whole error with the multi-line traceback. If that's the actual reply, then I think that points to a specific issue with the request itself and how the website you're calling handles that request. Check the status code and content of the response and get back to us?

Comment: its a message, starts with "

Comment: Its a message, the status code is 200. The message appears when I put r.text. It seems that the page is like protected because it only bring me the text that is on the bottom of the page.


have you ever had this problem? First I have a message that says:

Comment: "    !doctype html>\n<html ng-app="consultatioPlusApp">\n\n<head>\n    <meta charset="utf-8">\n    <title></title>\n    <meta name="description" content="">\n    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">\n    <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->\n    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/styles/vendor.css">\n    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/styles/main.css">\n</head>\n\n<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">\n\n    <!--[if lte IE 8]>\n    <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.co

Comment: I think "outdated browser" means you need to pass `{"User-Agent": something}` to the `headers` kwarg. List of user agents: http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php

Comment: Actually if you run the code with any user a pw, you will get the same message. Sorry for commenting lots of time. Its my first time in Stackoverflow.

Comment: Im trying with the following code:


import requests

url = 'https://micuenta.consultatioplus.com/#!/login'
endpoint = '/endpoint-you-ultimately-want'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'}

s= requests.Session()



r=requests.Session().get(url+endpoint,headers=headers, auth=('ex', 'pw'))

Comment: You aren't literally using the stand-in endpoint `/endpoint-you-ultimately-want` right? Please edit your original question to update us about what you've tried (so that you can write it out in code blocks)

Comment: Hehe sorry! 

url = 'https://micuenta.consultatioplus.com'
endpoint = '/#!/login'

But I still getting the same message

Comment: Ok but edit your post to show the code you are currently trying (obviously block out email and pw)

Answer (score 0):

Error 405 is `Method not allowed` - that means your server doesn't accept `POST` method in this url.

By inspecting the site with browser developer tools, I can see that the login credentials are being sent to `https://profile.consultatioplus.com/v1/login/internal` and not to `https://micuenta.consultatioplus.com/#!/login`. Try this url instead?